# Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon, I was trying to export the values of 'nameValue' and 'passValue' to use them in another javascript file but I can't export them.

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

I am not using any framework or library (Javascript Vanilla only)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.info('This is running!')

  let name = document.getElementById('name')
  let password = document.getElementById('password')
  let loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    nameValue = name.value
    passValue = password.value 

    export {nameValue, passValue}

    event.preventDefault()
  })  
})
```

Comment: How do you expect the "other file" to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is trying to say that you can use `export` only at the top level of your code, i.e., not in a function body or similar. Your variables will need to be defined at that level, too.

```
let nameValue, passValue;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.info('This is running!')

  let name = document.getElementById('name')
  let password = document.getElementById('password')
  let loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    nameValue = name.value
    passValue = password.value 

    event.preventDefault()
  })  
})

export {nameValue, passValue}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you included a type=“module” attribute in the script tag

```html
<script src="example.js" type="module"><\script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include both script if you using export import to each other.

```
<script src="./assets/scripts/app.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./assets/scripts/util.js" ></script>
```